# how to add a 4 spaces in pyhon 3 idle or shell (space between lines)

Tags: python

```
a = 1
if a > 1: #hit enter
    print ("L") #hit enter
        print ("K") #add 4 spaces or press tab
#hit enter
```

SyntaxError: unexpected indent

[image]

Comment: Indentation carries meaning in Python. You can't just indent a line for no good reason.

Comment: What's the expected output? is it `'L    K'`?

Comment: This site really goes into the indentations in python! https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/concept-of-indentation-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 1
if a > 1: #hit enter
    print ("L"+"\n" ) #hit enter
    print ("K"+"\n") #add 4 spaces or press tab
#hit enter
```

The `\n` adds a line break after the string. Like hitting enter in some text editor, or like `<br>` in HTML

Answer (score 1):

The indent in the second print statement is unwanted. Don't add the extra 4 spaces on `print ("K")`. Its indentation level already matches the `if` block.

Comment: well lets say i wanted to use (else) HOW can i add a 4 spaces (can u make a code please)